# Supporting anonymous users in Angular app w/ Web API and ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I have an AngularJS app which uses an ASP.NET Web API backend (with OWIN/token-based auth) that in turn implements ASP.NET Identity for easy registration & login.  The frontend and backend apps are both housed within the same project/site to reduce CORS-related issues, and with an eye towards allowing the app to leverage ASP.NET's server-side auth for users.  I'd like to also enable the handling of anonymous users to allow certain site actions to be taken without registration being required.  ASP.NET provides an  element and an AnonymousIdentificationModule class...can anyone help me understand whether I could leverage that as well in this stack for dealing with anonymous users?

Comment: just don't add the `Authorize` attribute on the controller actions that are anonymous; if the entire controller has `authorize`, then use the `AllowAnonymous` attribute on the specific anonymous actoins....

Answer (score 0):

Controllers and their ActionResults are anonymous by default.  You need to use the `[Authorize]` attribute to apply any sort of security filtering.  Therefore, just do not add `[Authorize]` to the actions which you wish to be anonymous.  If you are using `[Authorize]` at the controller instead of the action level, then use `[AllowAnonymous]` on the specific action which should not be authenticated.

Comment: I understand the authorization needs of the API, but let's say I have a shopping cart and an anonymous user fills it up.  On the backend I have ShoppingCart database entities keyed to my AspNetUser (ASP.NET Identity) table...can ASP.NET Identity handle creating records for anonymous users, does it work in conjunction with ASP.NET's anonymousIdentification element, and is there any example of using this backend mechanism with basically an HTML-only client application rather than MVC/Web Forms?